# Rank of cross-covariance matrix

Tags: pr.probability, matrices, st.statistics, matrix-analysis

Let $\boldsymbol{X}=(X_1,\dots,X_p)^T$ and $\boldsymbol{Y}=(Y_1,\dots,Y_q)^T$ be two random vectors. Denote $r_x=\text{rank}(\text{Cov}(\boldsymbol{X})),r_y=\text{rank}(\text{Cov}(\boldsymbol{Y})), r_{(x,y)}=\text{rank}(\text{Cov}([\boldsymbol{X}^T,\boldsymbol{Y}^T]^T))$, and $r_{xy}=\text{rank}(\text{Cov}(\boldsymbol{X},\boldsymbol{Y}))$, where $\text{Cov}(\boldsymbol{X},\boldsymbol{Y})=[\text{Cov}(X_i,Y_j)]_{p\times q}$.

Given $r_x,r_y,r_{(x,y)}$,
can $r_{xy}$ be represented by a formula of $r_x,r_y,r_{(x,y)}$?

If not, is it correct that $r_{xy}\ge r_x+r_y-r_{(x,y)}$?

Comment: Since $a^TCov(X)a=Var(a^TX)$ we have $r_x=p$ unless there exist $a$ with $Var(a^TX)\neq 0$. Similar for $r_y$.